# Select multiple range using matlab activex server

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

I want to write the results of a data analysis with MATLAB to an Excel spreadsheet. To get it more handy and nice I also tried to format the content.

Because formatting every single cell or range is very slow I tried to format a multiple range - but I didn't manage to get it running.

I recorded a macro directly with **Excel** that shows in principle, what I wanted to do:

```
    Range("B355:AG359,B365:AG369").Select
    Range("B365").Activate
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

Now I tried to translate it to my **MATLAB** code ...

```
    xls = actxserver('Excel.Application');         
    xlsDatei = xls.Workbooks.Open(xlsFileName);    
    myBook = xlsDatei.Sheets.Item(p);
    myBook.Activate; 
    myRange = myBook.Range('B355:AG359,B365:AG369');
    ...
```

And this is the point - I always the following MATLAB error:

> *Error using Interface.000208D8_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/Range Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC*

Perhaps there who has done this before and can help me.

Comment: Not sure in Matlab, but in Excel VBA you have to `Set myRange = myBook.Range(...)`. Is there an equivalent perhaps in Matlab?  Also, technically, `myBook` isn't a workbook reference from what I can tell, may want to change the variable name just for readability...Also, have you [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+Object+returned+error+code%3A+0x800A03EC) your question and tried any of the suggested solutions?

Comment: Normaly if you want to set a range in Matlab you only need to write something like ```myRange = myBook.Range('B1:B3');``` this works perfekt! But in my special case, i wan't to setup a **multiple range** - and that's exactly the point that ends up in an error.

Comment: Try `myRange = myBook.Range('B355:AG359','B365:AG369');`. That's work for me

Comment: I tried it by my self and your right - you don't get an error. But if you look at the result in your Excel Spreedsheet, you will see, that **only the first range** (in this case 'B355:AG359') **is affected**. I tried to change the background color to red and only the first of both ranges was changed to red. No matter what I tried - the second range was not affected.

Comment: Minor note: your `myBook` variable is actually a reference to a `Worksheet` object, not a `Workbook` object. That distinction might help you find the right documentation more easily. Unfortunately, the relevant doco is this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range - and it seems to say that your "comma" approach should work. Sorry about that; working with ActiveX interfaces from Matlab is hard.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could try switching from the ActiveX interface to using the [.NET Office Interop API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019), which also works from Matlab. In my experience, some things work with the ActiveX interface but not the .NET interface, and other things are vice versa. You could also avoid Office interop entirely and generate your XLS files using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) called from Matlab. Though that's going to be really slow too, unless you write a little wrapper for it.